# c++ Bracket Validator with Stacks

Tags: c++, validation, stack, brackets

I'm trying to write a program that will validate a user input consisting of brackets for proper nesting using a stack.  I am trying to do this without the use of STL containers or recursion. I have somewhat hit a road block and I'm looking for a little nudge in the right direction.  I think I am kind of close, but I feel like I may be oversimplifying it (I'm in the process of learning through self teaching)

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayStack.h"
using namespace std;

bool test(char *argg);

int main()
{
    string input;
    int size = 50;

    cout << "enter here: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        test(input[i]);
}

bool test(char *argg)
{
    ArrayStack S;
    char D;
    while ( *argg ) {
        switch( *argg ) {

            case '[': case '{': case '(':
                S.push( *argg );
                break;

            case ']':
                if( S.isEmpty() )
                    return false;
                D = S.pop();
                if( D!='[' )
                    return false;
                break;

            case '}':
                if( S.isEmpty() )
                    return false;
                D = S.pop();
                if( D!='{' )
                    return false;
                break;

            case ')':
                if( S.isEmpty() )
                    return false;
                D = S.pop();
                if( D!='(' )
                   return false;
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }// end switch
                   argg++;
    }// end while

    return S.isEmpty(); // return true if reach here with empty stack

}
```

Thanks for any assistance in advance

Comment: why are you not telling that what your problem is (it seems that it is that the code does not compile)? anyway, at least two others have asked about the same homework task today/yesterday, so look at those answers. general observation: instead of declaring a function before `main` and defining it after, why not *just* define it before `main`, huh?

Comment: I could swear I saw two of these questions popping up in the last few hours, but I can't seem to find them...

Comment: Yeah he did ask the same question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373159/stack-of-chars-to-check-balanced-brackets

Comment: Why do you not use stl??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything, you're overcomplicating it

```
char inverse(char c){
   if(c==']') return '[';
   if(c=='}') return '{';
   if(c==')') return '('; 
   return c;
}
int stillvalid(char c, ArrayStack &stack){
   if(strchr("[{(", c))
        stack.push(c);
    else if(strchr("]})", c))
        if(stack.isEmpty() || inverse(c) != stack.pop())
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int c;
    ArrayStack stack;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
       if(!stillvalid((char)c, stack)){
           printf("bad\n");
           exit(0);
       }
    }
    printf("good\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Should be all you need.

Comment: Thats incorrect given the string "a", and ArrayStack should probably be passed by reference

Comment: except is doesn't pull any user input into the... what is strchr?

Comment: Correct about passing the stack by reference, I'll change that. Strchr returns a pointer to the first instance of a character in a string, or null if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Trace through your code by hand with the input `myfunc(42);`

Observe what happens, character by character.  That should point you your errors.